# Github pages is giving me 404 instead of linking to a different page

Tags: html, github, github-pages, github-desktop

I started building a website 2 days ago, I made a navbar, but when I click on an item I get a "404 File not found".
I have checked the linking what feels like 100 times and everything seems to be right.
If you want to check the code this is the repository: https://github.com/ancientgreeksters/ancientgreeksters.github.io

And the code for the navbar that is supposed to link is **in the "de" folder**, index.html file, line 27

I have checked the website locally on my pc and it works, so this seems to be a github issue.
I have also taken a look at similar questions here on stackoverflow, but they don't seem to be sharing the same issue as I am.

If you want to look at the website itself, the start page is working: https://ancientgreeksters.github.io/de/index.htm

But the page I am linking to doesn't work: https://ancientgreeksters.github.io/de/grammatik/uebersicht.html

Edit: I'm rather new to programming, so please dumb any suggestions down for me, if possible.

Comment: Case sensitive, your link is for https://ancientgreeksters.github.io/de/grammatik/uebersicht.html but the page is accessible on https://ancientgreeksters.github.io/de/Grammatik/uebersicht.html

Comment: @Martheen Wow, thank you. I can't believe I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the path. The folder is named `Grammatik` but the URL uses `grammatik`.

Rename the folder to `grammatik` to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! As said i'm new and didn't know html was case-sensitive.
I will accept your answer as soon as I can.